# How to find extensive Ruby version changelogs?

Tags: ruby, version

At the company where I am working, there is a huge codebase currently running on Ruby 1.6.8 (2002), which I am tasked with updating to the latest possible version.

There already exists a documentation, which explains how to update the code to Ruby 1.9.3, but even then there is not much documentation which explains the changes which 2.x introduced.

This documentation is also not ideal for me, since it wasn't extensive enough. Is there a website where I can find the changelogs for every Ruby version?

Comment: Does 'extensive' mean `git log`? Or are you just looking for an overview?

Comment: I was just looking for an overview, the other answer was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/releases/ are the changelogs of each version.